# Why is dipole potential independent of azimuthal angle?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential, dipole, dipole-moment

In the formula for dipole potential in spherical coordinates, there is no dependence on azimuthal angle. I don't see why this is as by varying the azimuthal angle, i.e changing our position on the x y plane, we are changing our distance to each of the charge, and so the potential due to each charge will change depending on our azimuthal angle. Even if we assume this distance to be negligible, why does polar angle affect potential then? My intuition says that the potential should only have a radial dependence. Can someone explain what symmetry I am not understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you would orientate the x-y plane, however, the usual way would be to choose the direction of the dipole, i. e. the connection line between both charges, along the z-axis. A reasonable x-y plane with respect to the dipole axis =z-axis would be the symmetry plane perpendicular to the z-axis and symmetric to the charges so that the distance of  any arbitrary point on this plane from one charge is the same as the distance to the other charge of the dipole (i.e. the origin of such a chosen coordinate system is right in the middle between both charges). 
At any point of x-y symmetry plane the potential of the dipole would be zero as the contributions of both charges cancel each other (as the distance to both charges is the same and the charges are opposite). So any angle dependence given by polar coordinates on the symmetry x-y plane does not exist. Such an angle is usually called the azimuthal angle. In different words, one would not expect any dependence on such an angle as the distance to the dipole does not change by changing this angle.

On the contrary the angle between the dipole axis=z-axis and the position vector of the point where the potential is measured matters. If such a point is for example again in the x-y symmetry plane this angle would be $90^{\circ}$. As we already know that the potential is zero at such a point one can guess that the potential of the dipole is apparently proportional to the scalar product of the dipole axis vector and the position vector of the point where the potential is measured (the scalar product is $\sim \cos \theta$). So the potential of the dipole depends on the angle (actually $\sim\cos\theta$) between these two vectors, this angle, however, is typically identified with the polar angle. If the potential of the dipole is measured at a point (excluding the origin) on the z-axis, this angle would be zero and the potential would be proportional to the product of dipolar moment  and the distance to this chosen point ($\cos\theta=1$) and another additional factor $\frac{q}{r^3}$ ($r$ being the distance of the origin (in the middle of the dipole) to the point where the potential is measured), so definitively the potential of a dipole is strongly radially dependent (assuming the cgs unit system and $q$ be the charge of one of dipole charges).

Of course the dependence of the potential on the scalar product of the dipole moment vector and the position vector of the point where the potential is measured multiplied with $\frac{q}{r^3}$ is maintained at any chosen point in space.

Answer (score 1):

The dipole is symmetric about its axis, hence the azimuthal symmetry.   If the dipole is oriented along $\hat z$ (as it done usually) and one uses cylindrical coordinates with $\hat z$ as the axis of the cylinder, it is clear geometrically that  points at constant height $z$ and constant $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, i.e. point in a plane perpendicular to the axis of the dipole and on a circle of radius $\rho$, are all equivalent in the sense that a rotation of the dipole by an angle $\varphi$ in the plane will not change the charge distribution.

This invariance is reflected in the independence of the potential on the azymuthal $\phi$ coordinate.  When going to spherical coordinates, the definition of the azimuthal angle as the angle in the $xy$ plane *coincides* with the cylindrical definition, and thus the independence on this angle remains.